# Error al descargar archivos grandes desde un FTP

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

hice un código que descarga archivos desde un servidor FTP, y el código funciona bien con archivos pequeños hasta 200mb, pero cuando el archivo es muy pesado (4GB), me lanza el error "Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException'", el error lo lanza después de terminar la función, cuando devuelve el file, se queda como 5 minutos y luego lanza el error.

Alguien sabe como solucionar?

estoy usando .NET MVC con el framework 4.7

```
[HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public FileResult DescargarArchivo(int? id)
       {
           if (!id.HasValue){return null;}
           var file = db.Software.Find(id);
           if (file == null){return null;}
           var categoria = db.CategoriaSoftware.Find(file.tipocategoria);
           if (categoria == null) { return null; }
           var tipo = db.TipoSoftware.Find(categoria.tiposoftware);
           if (tipo == null) { return null; }
           string ruta = host + tipo.nombreTipo + "/" + categoria.nombreCategoria + "/" + file.nombrearchivo;
           var ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ruta);
           ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
           ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
           ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
           ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
           ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
           var ftpResponse = ftpRequest.GetResponse();
           var ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
           int index = ftpResponse.ResponseUri.Segments.Length-1;
           string nombre = ftpResponse.ResponseUri.Segments[index];
           string content = "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "+nombre;//ftpResponse.ContentType;
           return File(ftpStream, content, nombre);
       }
```